# Find all parents elements in a Json file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I'm currently working on a recursive menu which is built on top of jQuery which looks quite good already.

The structure of the JSon file containing the menu looks as the following:

```
[
   { 
       "Id": "menuOfficeWebControlsForWebApplication", 
       "Title": "Office Web Controls", 
       "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/index.html" },
   { 
       "Id": "menuGettingStarted", 
       "Title": "Getting Started", 
       "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/getting-started.html", 
       "Categories": [{ 
             "Id": "menuCompilingFromSource", 
             "Title": "Compiling From Source", 
             "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/Getting-Started/compiling-from-source.html" 
          },{ 
             "Id": "menuDownloadReleasePackage", 
             "Title": "Download Release Package", 
             "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/Getting-Started/downloading-release-package.html"
          },{ 
             "Id": "menuBuildingYourFirstApplication", 
             "Title": "Building your first application", 
             "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/Getting-Started/building-your-first-application.html" 
        }]
   }
]
```

Now, I can retrieve an item out of the menu using jQuery and the result might be this item:

```
{ 
   "Id": "menuBuildingYourFirstApplication", 
   "Title": "Building your first application", 
   "Resource": "/Documentation/Data/Getting-Started/building-your-first-application.html" 
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the elements which are at a higher level and all the items which are directly below that item.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is a parent? Any node that's not the current node? Can you alter the nodes in anyway (as to add a ParentNode property for example)

Comment: I could that that, but it's easy to have typo mistakes. A parent is an element which is higher in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery is for querying HTML elements from within the DOM of the current document, not for traversing objects or JSON expression strings.

In any case, given an object, there is no way to "discover" any objects, variables, or arrays that might hold a reference to it.

I'd recommend picking up a decent Javascript book and becoming familiar with the basics. Maybe stay away from things like JQuery at first as they can confuse things for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do now it's not possible now.

Comment: >  "[jQuery is] not for traversing objects or JSON expression strings."  
Yet it has many utility methods to do just that, from `$.parseJson` to `$.each`, to `$.filter`, `$.map` etc. However a library like underscore/lodash would be more useful when working with objects.